# If a user adds a comment to their own post, should it be added to the post itself?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I recently flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767666/how-to-make-semantic-input-with-text-choice-and-arrow-behavior-like-number-input/33769376#comment55306426_33769376) where a user comments on their own answer, with information that adds to the original answer, no more no less. I flagged this comment with a note that the comment ought to be removed and added as a whole to the answer itself to keep a nice overview.

However, this flag was declined and I'm confused as to why. Isn't this *exactly* what edits are for? Adding new information to your answer should always be done through edits, and not by commenting to your own question, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes comments like that are an afterthought, sometimes they're not terribly important, and sometimes they add significant details to the question or answer.

Instead of flagging it, if it is pertinent and essential to the question or answer and needs to be edited in, you should leave a comment instructing the user to do so (more common with OP comments on questions than answers), and if the OP does not respond by making the edit, go ahead and suggest the edit yourself.  Or if you feel confident enough in doing so, just suggest the edit outright.  There isn't much to be gained in flagging it before the content has been added to the post, because the moderators handling the flag would then have to do the edit you could have done yourself. That shifts a burden onto moderators that the community is already equipped to shoulder.

If after the edit was made the redundant comment remains, then you may consider flagging it as obsolete.

Comment: That's correct, the OP has sufficient privileges to edit directly but the majority of users who may read this do not.

Comment: If you suggest an edit, make sure to put "add information from asker's comment" or similar in the edit summary, or it's likely to be rejected as deviating from the original intent.

Answer (score 1):

If you can take an action yourself it is almost guaranteed to get flag declined. Same for actions that can be taken by community - "other: please close" and similar "other" would be declined.

I.e. in this case you have 2K+ reputation and could have made edit yourself.

Your real options:

- do nothing (unless comment makes answer wrong/invalid)
- comment to OP (assuming it OP is active on the site)
- make edit yourself (immediately if OP have not visited site recently, or for active users after some grace period you feel enough - 48+ hours would be my recommendation)

Comment: The problem is that, sure I can edited their post, but I cannot delete their comment. So because of that I'd better ask for a moderator's intervention so they can see the comment deleted. If I did edit the answer, and their comment didn't get deleted that'd lead to confusing duplication.

Comment: @BramVanroy Edit + flag comment as obsolete could work. Or Edit + "other: delete as comment inlined in the post". Basically don't flag for something you/community can perform - flag for actions only diamond mods can take.